# How to implement traits while using arenas in Rust?

Tags: rust

The [id-arena](https://crates.io/crates/id-arena) crate describes a simple example of using an arena to manage memory allocation in scenarios where you're okay with everything having a shared lifetime:

```rust
use id_arena::{Arena, Id};

type AstNodeId = Id<AstNode>;

#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub enum AstNode {
    Const(i64),
    Var(String),
    Add {
        lhs: AstNodeId,
        rhs: AstNodeId,
    },
    Sub {
        lhs: AstNodeId,
        rhs: AstNodeId,
    },
    Mul {
        lhs: AstNodeId,
        rhs: AstNodeId,
    },
    Div {
        lhs: AstNodeId,
        rhs: AstNodeId,
    },
}

let mut ast_nodes = Arena::<AstNode>::new();

// Create the AST for `a * (b + 3)`.
let three = ast_nodes.alloc(AstNode::Const(3));
let b = ast_nodes.alloc(AstNode::Var("b".into()));
let b_plus_three = ast_nodes.alloc(AstNode::Add {
    lhs: b,
    rhs: three,
});
let a = ast_nodes.alloc(AstNode::Var("a".into()));
let a_times_b_plus_three = ast_nodes.alloc(AstNode::Mul {
    lhs: a,
    rhs: b_plus_three,
});

// Can use indexing to access allocated nodes.
assert_eq!(ast_nodes[three], AstNode::Const(3));
```

This seems better for my use case than cloning structures each time they are reused. But, this approach makes it less clear how to implement basic traits on my data structures that use the returned `Id`s:

```rust
impl std::fmt::Display for AstNode {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            AstNode::Const(x) => write!(f, "{}", x),
            AstNode::Var(x) => write!(f, "{}", x),
            AstNode::Add { lhs, rhs } => // ??? how to obtain a ref to the original AstNode here?
        }
    }
}
```

The same issue arrises for other traits I'd like to implement like PartialEq as well.

More generally, what I'd love to do is come up with some implementation of "From" that lets me do something like this:

```rust
struct AstNodeId(Id<AstNode>);

impl From<AstNodeId> for &AstNode {
    fn from(t: TypeRef) -> Self {
        // ???
    }
}
```

... so that I can continue writing my code as if AstNodeId is just a Box or pointer to somewhere. But I'm not sure how I would implement this. With `id-arena`, I can't seem to create `Arena::new()` as a top-level `static` or `const` value so, global variables seem out of the question. Is there some other design pattern / solution that will allow me to do this?

Also, could interning be a solution here / used instead? When should I use interning vs arenas in Rust?

Comment: Typically the issue with formatting is solved by giving your `AstNodeId` a `with_context` function that accepts a reference to the arena and creates a temporary struct that you can implement `Debug` or `Display` for. As for traits such as `From`, you will need to get a bit more creative. `AstNodeId` might just be an index into the arena so there may not be enough information here to even determine which arena it corresponds to.

Comment: You have three solutions: create a `WithArena` struct as @Locke mentioned, create a `PartialEqWithArena` traits and friends, or switch to an arena implementation that gives references, e.g. [`bumpalo`](https://docs.rs/bumpalo).